# Do I need to get a license to use OS X system font in my app?

Tags: macos, applications, mac-appstore, font

I recently completed my first cocoa app and want to publish it (not via Mac App Store), I am using system font in my app and not bundling any font with my app itself.

Do I need to get permission to use the default system font in my app?

Answer (score 2):

No. If the font is not bundled, there is no need to license.

Comment: I don't think this post requires additional references. You are not distributing the fonts, rather than that you are using a system API. Of course you can use the API and the system fonts. Additionally you can use the system fonts in screenshots, mockups and print media depicting your application as granted by "APPLE INC.
LICENSE AGREEMENT FOR THE APPLE SAN FRANCISCO FONT" which you have to agree to if you DOWNLOAD the fonts https://developer.apple.com/fonts/

Comment: @Jozef This is the kind of information that should be within the answer.